# Convert string to Dictionary<string,byte>()

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a string that is formatted like this (the string is one continuous, no new line return)

```
 /CallDump/CallInfo/KVP[@Key='Group' and (@Value='Best Group')]:10,
 /CallDump/CallInfo/child::KVP[@Key='Dept' and (@Value='Customer Service' or @Value='Sales')]:240,
 compare(Recordings/Recording/Location, 'New York')=0:20,
 default:5,
```

I cannot seem to find a non complex way to convert it into a dictionary()

results would be something like this:

Key: /CallDump/CallInfo/KVP[@Key='Group' and (@Value='Best Group')]    Value: 10

Key: compare(Recordings/Recording/Location, 'New York')=0    Value: 20

Comment: `Dictionary<string.byte>()` --- what does it mean?

Comment: Assuming there is an input string `"11"` what result do you expect to get?

Comment: I think what you need is a tree structure like xml.  Or a more definite idea of what data you want included in the dictionary.

Comment: @Chadit : I think we really need more information.  Here is the specific items that should be clarified:  For the string you show, what key/value pairs do you expect?  Although the answer given by MarcinJuraszek is quite impressive, my suspicion is that it is not really what you are looking for.  So if you can clarify that for us, the help you receive will be more likely to be on point.

Comment: Added and example of the key value pairs.. thanks all for your help so far

Comment: Given your clarifying edit, MarcinJuraszek's answer meets your request.

Comment: updated the post, sorry I did not clarify, there is no newline in the string, it is one continuous string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this with `Regex` and LINQ:

```
var input = @"/CallDump/CallInfo/KVP[@Key='Group' and (@Value='Best Group')]:10,
 /CallDump/CallInfo/child::KVP[@Key='Dept' and (@Value='Customer Service' or @Value='Sales')]:240,
 compare(Recordings/Recording/Location, 'New York')=0:20,
 default:5,";

var expression = new Regex(@"(.+):(\d{1,3})");

var result = input.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  .Select(x => x.Trim())
                  .Select(x => expression.Match(x))
                  .Select(m => new { Key = m.Groups[1].Value, Value = byte.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value) })
                  .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Returns `Dictionary<string, byte>` with four elements.

Comment: When I put this into LinqPad, it gives this:    
Key: /CallDump/CallInfo/KVP[@Key='Group' and (@Value='Best Group')] Value: 10 
Key: /CallDump/CallInfo/child::KVP[@Key='Dept' and (@Value='Customer Service' or @Value='Sales')]   Value: 240 
Key: compare(Recordings/Recording/Location, 'New York')=0   Value: 20 
Key: default Value: 5

Is this really the "key" the OP was looking for?  I was thinking maybe the first pair would be Key: Group  Value: Best Group  Then with the 'or' word in the "child" line, I was thinking it might be a GroupBy Grouping<TKey, TValue).

Comment: There is `Dictionary<string, byte>` in question title. That's the only way to get one from provided input string I can think about.

Comment: @MartinJuascek : I agree with you, so I asked the OP for clarification in a comment.  If he really is trying to pull @ Key and @ Value out of that, I doubt there will be any algorithm that could be called "non complex".

Comment: Works great with your example, sorry I did not clarify there is no newline return value, I formatted it that way in hopes it would be easier to read